# Taking in variables and returning a tuple for mutation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++17

I'm trying to change the state of a couple of variables by passing it to a function, but without passing them as references. I find it cleaner to take in variables and return them.

I don't like using `std::move` so often, but it looks like I have to use them to avoid the copies?

Is the following way of doing so ok, or is it more of an anti-pattern?

```
std::tuple<A, B> foo(A a, B b) {
    // Some logic that needs A and B
    // Mutates A and B
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(a), std::move(b));
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    std::tie(a, b) = foo(std::move(a), std::move(b));
}
```

Comment: Any reason why not `void foo(A&, B&)`?

Comment: I can take the variables by reference, but I just find it a bit cleaner to not let `foo` have side effects like that. Maybe I'm overthinking it

Comment: You have asked for a specific kind of solution, which is fair enough. However, for information, admittedly not knowing your reasons, I would likely avoid this kind of solution. I would explicitly pass addresses, rather: `foo(A *const pa, B *const pb);` I agree with you however that the `move` is not ideal. Still, it is not for me to change your question to a different question! I would assume that you have your reasons.

Comment: My team's lead recommends (for value objects) doing exactly what you have.  Pass by copied-value, and then `std::move`.  He's on the C++ WG21, so he's pretty well informed.

Comment: I don't know what your specific use case is, but when I write functions with side effects, I just give them a name that makes it clear. If you don't always want to mutate the original values, make two versions. Call one `doWork` and the other `mutatingDoWork` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is perfectly correct: the function's signature leaves it to the caller if either a copy shall be made by calling:

```
foo(a, b)
```

or the objects shall be moved into the function:

```
foo(std::move(a), std::move(b))
```

The latter does not involve any copying, so it has a good run time performance (provided that the move constructors of A and B are "cheap-to-move").

Also, your function's input/output design is the preferred one (according to https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-out) while using "IN/OUT" parameters is not.

Last but not least in multi threading programs, passing by reference can cause access to dangling references, e. g. if foo is executed in a different thread than a/b are destroyed. Passing parameters by value avoids dangling references by design.

Comment: In-out params are discussed in a previous section https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f17-for-in-out-parameters-pass-by-reference-to-non-const
It's considered safe if you have the appropriate warnings enabled in your linting tools or IDE.